# How to pass bool flag from Razor syntax to javascript

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to pass a variable like this:

```
<script>
var isWhiteLabel = @isWhiteLabel == True ? true : false;

//renders as follows in my Sources tab:
var isWhiteLabel = True == True ? true : false;
//in my output console error: 
//Uncaught ReferenceError: True is not defined
</script>
```

How can I pass this, to render as javascript variable (true/false)?